# XMLHttpRequest body cut off when using unicode

Tags: javascript, json, unicode, xmlhttprequest

I'm having a problem with XMLHttpRequest cutting off the body of a json encoded message when using Emoji's in the body.

```
var emoji = '"\u2764\uFE0F"';

var data = {
        id: messageid, time: new Date(),
        layout: { 'type': "message", title: emoji, body: emoji, largeIcon: "http://site/icons/icon.png", foregroundColor: "#445566", backgroundColor: "#222222" },
        createNotification: {
             layout: { 'type': "genericNotification", title: emoji, subtitle: emoji, largeIcon: "http://site/icons/icon.png" }
             }
   };

jsonenc = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log(jsonenc) //displays data fine.

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('PUT', dict.url, true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-16');
request.setRequestHeader('X-User-Token', dict.token);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);

request.send(dict.data);
```

If I console.log the json data, the data is at the full length, but if I look at the request under mitmproxy, it's cut off as such:

```
{"id":"messageid-123456","time":"2015-05-29T03:43:17.566Z","layout":{"type":"message","title":"\"......\"","body":"\"......\"","largeIcon":"http://site/icons/icon.png","foregroundColor":"#445566","backgroundColor":"#222222"},"createNotification":{"layout":{"type":"genericNotification""title":"\"......\"","subtitle":"\"......\"","largeIcon":"http://site/icons/ic
```

Answer (score 1):

```
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-16');
```

There is no `charset` parameter for the `application/json` media type. If there were, UTF-16 would be the wrong choice. When XMLHttpRequest sends a JS `String` it encodes it as UTF-8.

```
request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
```

This doesn't do anything. XMLHttpRequest always fills in the Content-Length from the length of the data you send and ignores this call. If it didn't, `data.length` would be the wrong value, because that's a length in UTF-16 code units but Content-Length is measured in bytes.

> if I look at the request under mitmproxy, it's cut off as such:

That would seem to be a problem with mitmproxy's user interface.

```
"title":"\"......\""
```

U+2764,U+FE0F gets encoded to UTF-8 as bytes 0xE2,0x9D,0xA4,0xEF,0xB8,0x8F. mitmproxy only displays the ASCII stream data without attempting to decode as any other encoding, so it displays each top-bit-set byte as the placeholder `.`.

Comment: >That would seem to be a problem with mitmproxy's user interface.


If I look at the data with flask, it's cut off at the exact same spot.


`{"id":"messageid-123456","time":"2015-05-29T13:34:19.357Z","layout":{"type":"message","title":"\"❤️\"","body":"\"❤️\"","largeIcon":"http://site/icons/icon.png","foregroundColor":"#445566","backgroundColor":"#222222"},"createNotification":{"layout":{"type":"genericNotification","title":"\"❤️\"","subtitle":"\"❤️\"","largeIcon":"http://site/icons/ic`

Comment: Is the code accurate? What is `dict.data`? I was guessing this was a mistake and you meant to send `jsonenc`.